# How to set views filters of a certain column name is equal to the logged in user name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-views

How will i set filters in views where a column name will be equal to logged in user name.. like if someone loggs in they will be able to view their items only. The items can be uploaded by anyone so submitted by me wont work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this

[image]

Replace **Created By** column name with your custom column which store the user name. 
the equation will be like this

**Custom Column is equal to [ME]**

Then it will shows only the records which are belongs to login user